# C# Combobox index in displaymember

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox that has a BindingList as its DataSource. I've set the displaymember to the property I want being displayed. For some objects in that list the property is empty so I would like to display the index of the object inside that BindingList (preferably a combination of both, the index followed by the property). How can I let the index be displayed inside the combobox and not a property (I can't get the index inside the object so I can't create a new property)?

Comment: Okay.  Go ahead and do it.  Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdownlist asks for the name of the property and doesn't accept any logic to attach to it. So you have to add an extra column to your datasource consists of the information from those two columns.